# 403 Forbidden when I send POST request

Tags: php, curl, post, http-status-code-403

Good evening, I wanted to connect to the https://accounts.nintendo.com/ site via twitter with cURL, so I first made a GET request on the nintendo site connection page to get the csrf_token and then a POST request to the action url of the nintendo site form in order to connect via twitter.

Normally when everything is going well the answer request should send me back: 302 Found then the oAuth link to connect me via twitter.

I tried of modify the userAgent and Header

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// SHOW THE PAGE TO GET CSRF TOKEN
$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'https://accounts.nintendo.com/login';



curl_setopt_array($ch,
  array(
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,

     CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem",
     CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => false,
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36",
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
       'Host: accounts.nintendo.com',
       'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
       'Pragma: ',

       'Connection: keep-alive',

     ),
     CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
     CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt",
     CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt",
     CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => false,


    // The data to transfer with the response.

    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,


  )
);


$data = curl_exec($ch);


// PARSER THE TOKEN CSRF
$dom = new simple_html_dom();

$html = $dom->load($data);


foreach($html->find('li[class="LoginForm_snsButton LoginForm_snsButton-row LoginForm_snsButton-twitter"] input[name="csrf_token"]') as $element)
{
  $csrf_token = $element->value.'<br/>';

}

curl_close($ch);

//SEND POST REQUEST

$ch2 = curl_init();

$url = 'https://accounts.nintendo.com/federation/twitter';


$postData = array(

  "post_federation_redirect_uri" => "https://accounts.nintendo.com/",
  "post_federation_reauthenticate" => "",
  "redirect_after" => "5",
  "csrf_token" => $csrf_token,
  "display" => ""
);
curl_setopt_array($ch2,
  array(
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,

     CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem",
     CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => false,
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",


     CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt",
     CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt",
     CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => false,
     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postData),
     CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    // The data to transfer with the response.
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,


  )
);

$exec = curl_exec($ch2);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch2);
echo $header['request_header'].'</br></br></br>';

echo $header['header_size'];

echo $exec;
curl_close($ch2);


?>
```

the problem is that I get a nice 403 Forbidden (I don't know if it's because I'm making the request from localhost), here's a screen showing the request header, the response header and the content of the site's response: http://www.noelshack.com/2019-15-6-1555110358-screenshot-1.jpg

Comment: According to your screenshot and the Nintendo login page, you need to pass a Google reCAPCTHA check and you are not passing it. As a result, Nintendo seems to throw a 403.

Answer (score -2):

What is your **chmod permission** for *simple_html_dom.php* and for your script ?

If you did not put permission **644** try this :

Chmod both files with `$chmod 644 YourScript.php`

And, in a second case reload your script on your Web-Browser and wait for *error 403* and look on your Log File.

- In case you use **Apache2** look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`
- Otherwise or if you use **Nginx** go in
  `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Give me your results so I could help you a little better. ;)

Comment: The `403 Forbidden` error is coming from the remote host, Nintendo in this case. Changing the file permissions of the script will not help with this.

Comment: The solution of loukandreys don't work (also, the chmod permission is not the problem). Also, i tried change HTTP REFERER but it not change :/

Comment: Oh exact sorry I did not see the screenshot. @johannes is right the problem seems to be related to Google's ReCaptcha.

sorry for the bad way

Comment: @Errorj404 Have a look at my comment on your initial question. I think it's very unlikely that you are able to pass the reCAPCTHA because your behavior is one Nintendo wants to prevent by using reCAPCTHA.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this but it will violate the Nintendo terms (at least).

Comment: +1 @Johannes .. First , Errorj404 you are on the wrong forum .. And second if you ask this question you are far from coming to your end .. You have clearly not the skills .